# Stereo I2S To USB Audio

Tags: usb, audio

I have searched for a way to convert an I2S stream to USB audio and have only managed to find USB to I2S, not I2S to USB. Please advise me as to how this is possible.

Comment: A DSP with I2S and USB interfaces would be a general answer to your general question.

Comment: A DSP such as??

Comment: Without researching the details, a guess as to a key problem may be clocking (presumably the I2S source is providing a clock, not accepting one, though that would be possible).  Likely you can find what you want, at least in the form of a toslink type optical S/PDIF input on professional audio gear.  But it may be better to see if there isn't a better path to solving your actual problem.  **What are you really trying to do?**

Comment: I take analog inputs into a PCM3168 (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm3168a.pdf) and take an output of I2S which I want to be converted to digital USB audio.

Comment: You can do this with most microcontrollers with a USB peripheral and I2S peripheral, the USB audio spec is freely available and quite straightforward

Comment: There is not really a thing called 'USB audio'. What are you feeding the USB into?

Comment: Ideally into a Type A socket on a computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I take analog inputs into a PCM3168
>   (ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm3168a.pdf) and take an output of I2S which I
>   want to be converted to digital USB audio
>
> Ideally into a Type A socket on a computer

Now it is clear that the question exposes substantial gap in understanding of USB system architecture and related economy of development.

The audio I2S streams can not just be "sent" to "USB audio", they are just raw digital data formats for audio codecs. Which means that audio signals gets digitized (with high accuracy/resolution) and are converted into I2S digital serial format.

On the other end, the "USB audio" is a very detailed specification for the specific class of USB devices to handle audio streams. The Audio Class has to be implemented in a MCU that handles the I2S streams from PCM3168 "Audio Codec", and bridges these streams into USB-defined format. The transport interface is bi-directional, audio USB can output sound and read microphone (or line) inputs.

Technically you can implement any USB interface to bridge the I2S streams with USB streams, but you will be facing enormous development time for your PC drivers. But if you manage to implement all elements of Audio Class Device, implement all USB descriptors and endpoints correctly, and obey all the requirements for data buffering and throttling and clock synchronization, you will immensely benefit form existence of Windows and Linux/Unix/Android audio device drivers. To get a sense of what the USB audio implementation means, this [SiLabs appnote](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN295.pdf) might be useful. You also might want to familiarize yourself with the 130-page actual [specification](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/audio10.pdf).

Overall, it would probably take 3-4 engineering man-years to implement the idea of taking PCM3168 to some MCU (or DSP) and implement audio class USB device.

Alternatively people are using [standard USB dongles](https://www.walmart.com/c/kp/usb-audio-adapters) for input (recording) and output (headpones or line-out) of simple stereo signals, where all the above is already implemented and integrated into a single IC, so the street prices for these dongles are $1 - $15.

[image]

If you need more sophisticated audio I/O with extra quality, HiFi and low 130 dB noise level, something like [Creative Labs Soundblaster](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16829102103) will start from about $150.

Still it would be difficult to beat these prices facing 3-4 years of learning and development.

Comment: Beware those cheap dongles have only mono in even though they are stereo out.  Granted, that may be enough for the unclearly stated orginal need motivating this question.

Comment: What are you talking about?  There are I2S to USB bridge ICs available, and they come with drivers.  The OP does not need to create a solution from scratch.

Comment: @Stephen305, example of I2S to USB please.

Comment: CMedia chips are widely used in USB audio adapters (https://www.cmedia.com.tw/products/USB20_HIGH_SPEED).  The drivers are already included in Windows OS and the Linux kernel.  Another option is the CP2615 from Silicon Labs is a chip made just for this purpose.  It comes with drivers.  Note that it is not compatible with all other ICs that output I2S (I found this out the hard way).  Yet another option is a microcontroller like the Cypress PSoC6.  Cypress makes software libraries that are pretty much plug and play, if you know how to do a C programming.

Answer (score 2):

> I have searched for a way to convert an I2S stream to USB audio ...is it possible?

I think you are thoroughly confused at the difference between a control channel/device driver, a data format and an interface.

USB Audio as a spec does NOT specify the data format. It is a USB based control system for Audio output and input. See the USB Audio 3.0 spec [here](https://usb.org/sites/default/files/USB_Audio_v3.0.zip), and read Audio30.pdf within the zip file.

This will explain that USB Audio can 'control' endpoints that consume either analog or digital data.

Read further into Frmts30.pdf and you'll find that you could transport PCM (I2S uses PCM audio format) over the data channel and consume/convert in an endpoint of your design ….all controlled by USB Audio.

I2S is the interface definition for clocking PCM data from one chip to another. NXP have not maintained a spec in many years, but many others keep updating it, [this](https://www.cypress.com/file/133906/download) definition from Cypress does a good job.

So there is NO conversion for I2S to USB Audio since I2S is a data format and USB Audio is a control system. 
You could extract the PCM audio data from an I2S stream (but there are chips for that), and I'd bet you already have the data stream in a PCM format somewhere in your system.

Comment: could you give an example of these usb audio control chips?

Comment: Almost invariably they will be an MCU with inbuilt USB interface.

Comment: Does it have to be an MCU?

Comment: If it's to meet any significant number of USB Audio functions, then yes.

Comment: could it not somehow be done with an arduino

Comment: Is an Arduino not an MCU?

Comment: oh of course! how would one do it with an arduino

Comment: Start by reading the USB Audio stuff I pointed to, then design a system based on Arduino to implement that type of endpoint. Come back in a year or so and tell us how you are doing.

Comment: OK, thank you, you've answered my initial question so any more about the arduino part will be in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

[CM108](http://rats.fi/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/CM108_DataSheet_v1.6.pdf) meets your need (I2S to USB).

USB dongles of CM108 are sold for around $3.

Set pin ADSEL high to use I2S inputs instead of internal ADC.

---

correction: CM108 can only do mono recording, may not fit your need.

Comment: _”CM108 can do only mono recording, may not fit your need.”_ Just use two of them?

Comment: @Winny unusable if you want to record two channels simultaneously. Each chip shows itself as separate USB audio interface device. Rarely programs allow recording from more than one device at once. Also they both use their own clocks, so they are  asynchronous, and cheap crystals can have 20ppm tolerance so they will drift a millisecond worth of samples per minute. Even if modified to use same clock source, still the two streams could have some offset as the streams are initialized separately and come from different sources.

Comment: @Justme But on the USB side you will just read the stream. Imagine you run it for years, where will the GB worth of data difference between the two channels be stored due to clock difference? Don’t you just resample it on the USB side?

Comment: @winny How would the PC USB drivers possibly know how fast or slow the samples were sent compared to the nominal rate, to resample it? It is not the job of USB drivers to know that or resample. If it is a digital receive interface receiving bitstream instead of PCM, resampling would kill the bitstream.

Comment: @Justme Not sure exactly how, but  your assertion that they would drift apart in time would require data to be stored somewhere as time passes, and that memory does not exist in the system.

Comment: @winny No, it simply requires that one USB device has a clock that makes the sampling rate 48001 and the other a completely separate clock that makes the sampling rate 47999. That's why most audio recording programs will only record from one device at a time, as it is not guaranteed that different devices run in sync.

Comment: @Justme I see your point. Record two separate streams and resample it afterwards in software?

Comment: @winny Possible if you have do it in a one-off project the hard way, so why not. For any real purpose, such as even for hobby podcasting, you likely don't want to do it twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a USB to I2S bridge chip.  Silicon Labs makes the CP2615.  It even comes with drivers.  For $60, you can buy the evaluation kit.

See below

https://www.silabs.com/interface/usb-audio-bridges/device.cp2615

Comment: Beware that this device has precisely the limitation predicted: it must be allowed to clock the I2S stream, it *cannot* accept an *existing* I2S stream timed in relation to some other clock source.  It's quite possible that the OP could build a system by using this part to clock their ADC... but why would they *want to*?  They'd expend development time and cost, and probably end up with something with a naive circuit/board design around the ADC resulting in noise issues.  Really, the asker should just be buying a low-end "prosumer" USB audio digitizer product.

Comment: There is an ambiguity in OP request. Feeding I2S into "a Type A socket on a computer" might imply (a) making USB Audio Class Device with IN function (as a microphone typically), and (b) making a USB host that converts I2S into USB host  as Audio Class OUTPUT (for consumption by USB speakers etc.). My answer was mainly for the interpretation (b). For the case (a), as @ChrisStratton duly noted, there is a conflict: both CP2615 and PCM3168 are I2S masters. Maybe there are slave audio ADCs, I didn't look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Sound card CMI6206 supports 2 microphones for about $20.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to reclock all the I2S signals using phase lock loop, Hartley Oscillator, it you want it to sound correct. This also improve the S/N and distortion. We always re-clocked our converter input signals for the best performance in our data acquisition systems @TI seismic.