# Sending ADC I2S output to PC through USB port

Tags: adc, i2s

I want to use PCM1808PWR ADC at 96kHz 24-bit to convert analog instrument signal to digital (in short I want to build USB audio interface). How should I send I2S output from ADC through USB port? I want to keep it as simple as possible, rather without software development. It is meant to be a single, cheap board with 2 or 3 IC's in conversion part of circuit.

Comment: It does not have any I2C interface. This is only an ADC, you still need the USB audio interface part. And if you are not aware, you cannot directly connect instrument level devices like guitars to this ADC, you need suitable analog interfacing, and doing that so that it has even adequate quality will be a long task. I suggest buying the audio interface, unless you have access to measuring equipment worth a small car to determine the performance.

Comment: The PCM1808 [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm1808.pdf) indicates it has a ``I2S `` audio data interface format, whereas the question contains ``I2C output from ADC``. Can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/699990/edit) to clarify which _audio data interface format_ you intend to use. [What is the difference between I2S and I2C (I2C vs I2S )?](https://prodigytechno.com/i2c-vs-i2s/) might help to explain the different in terminology.

Comment: This is what USB device classes and descriptors are for.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo I meant I2S not I2C I know they're not the same, I edited my question

Comment: On a quick search found [PCM2706C USB to I2S](http://www.pavouk.org/hw/audiosystem20/en_pcm2706usbi2s.html) which is an example design which might help. Schematics and a PCB layout are available.

Comment: @Justme I know that instrument level devices need preamp with 1M input impedance, this preamp is meant to work with electric guitar and I know how to design and build one(btw it's not as hard as you describe it, especially for electric guitar which amplifiers and effects aren't meant to be hifi)

Comment: I don't want to use PCMxxxx series because they're hard to get in my country and quite expensive. Also this chip supports only 48kHz sampling rate and 16 bit depth

Comment: Also I know there are multiple USB to I2S converters but are they bi-directional or do I need I2S to USB? I couldn"t find it anywhere

Comment: I omitted to notice that you needed an I2S to USB converter, and the PCM2706C suggested above only supports the USB to I2S direction. Are you looking for a converter which needs no software development? If not perhaps something like a [Zybo Z7](https://digilent.com/reference/programmable-logic/zybo-z7/start#zybo_z7) could be used a starting point. It has a USB 2.0 interface and the [I2S Transmitter and I2S Receiver LogiCORE IP](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/pg308-i2s/IP-Facts?tocId=9FEzOdB8yo2s6RvSeJdRkA) can be used to implement a 24-bit I2S receiver in the programmable logic.

Comment: The Zybo Z7 also has a [SSM2603](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ssm2603.html) CODEC on board with a 24-bit ADC which supports a 96 kHz sampling rate with a stereo line input.

Answer (score 0):

### Checking answers to a different question

Found the question [Stereo I2S To USB Audio](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/430376/101063). Looking at the devices suggested in answers to that question to see if they will meet the requirements in this question:

1. [CM108 High Integrated USB Audio I/O Controller](https://rats.fi/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/CM108_DataSheet_v1.6.pdf). Doesn't meet the requirements since:

   - Mono recording only
   - 48 kHz maximum Sampling Rate
2. [CP2615](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/cp2615-datasheet.pdf). Doesn't meet the requirements since 48 kHz maximum Sampling Rate. It is also marked as *Not Recommended for New Designs*.

### Possible use of XMOS xCORE 200 based device

From further searching found some modules which are based upon the XMOS [XU208](https://www.xmos.com/download/XU208-256-TQ64-Datasheet(1.16).pdf). While the XU208 is a *xCORE Multicore Microcontroller*, XMOS provide reference software for USB Audio. E.g. see [Application Note: AN01027 Porting the XMOS USB 2.0 Audio Reference Software onto XU208 custom hardware](https://www.xmos.com/download/AN01027:-Porting-the-XMOS-USB-2.0-Audio-Reference-Software-onto-XU208-custom-hardware%281.0.0rc1%29.pdf)

An example module is [XMOS XU208 32Bit 384kHz DXD DSD256 DSD reclock SPDIF USB I2S in/out PCB](https://www.diyinhk.com/shop/audio-kits/170-2324-xmos-32bit-384khz-dxd-dsd256-usb-tofrom-i2sdsdreclock-spdif-pcb.html#/97-oled_panel-null/107-led_pcb-null/141-fifo_option-null/151-usb_socket-type_c_new_and_slim/153-optical_spdif_output_socket-null). That module could meet the requirements since since from the feature list:

1. Support up to 32bit 384kHz 2 channel input and 2 channel output or DSD256(native) two channel output. I2S input and output is working at the same sampling rate.
2. Supports a 96kHz LRCK (i.e. sample rate).
3. With the DIYINHK firmware, no driver is needed for Windows 10/11,Mac,Linux. I.e. no software development.
4. From the pictures of the PCB there are pads to connect the I2S signals and select the sample rate:
   [image]

From the information on the DIYINHK webpage it isn't clear if the firmware supports I2S in both master and slave modes, or only one mode. The PCM1808 ADC is described as support both modes, so even if the DIYINHK supports only one mode the PCM1808 should be able to set to a compatible mode.